# How can I set initial offset for first page in kaminari?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, kaminari

I need to implement some logic for to show 3 elements on the first page and by 1 element on  all the next. For the first page there is no problems:

```
items = @model.limit(@first_page_items)
```

and for all the next ones i tried:

```
@model.offset(@first_page_items).page(@current_page - 1).per(@per) #makes no offset at all - all the items going from the beginning
@model.page(@current_page - 1).per(@per).offset(@first_page_items) #produces 4-th element on the second page and stays on it for ever
```

What am I doing wrong? thx

Comment: Oh, Im stupid, sorry, already found - padding method - Kaminari::PageScopeMethods::padding(num), on the case if anyone will having the same issue