# Pagination messing up offset in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I only want to show posts starting with the second newest so am using 'offset(1)' in the controller (which i've used before with success) but it's not working since I need 'page(params[:page]).per_page(1)' at the end.

This does not offset:

```
@posts = Post.top.hide.offset(1).page(params[:page]).per_page(1)
```

This offsets but messes up the pagination:

```
@posts = Post.top.hide.page(params[:page]).per_page(1).offset(1)
```

I also tried putting it in the 'top' scope with the same results as above:

```
scope :top, (select('...').offset(1))
```

Comment: I recommend using the rails console to practice the queries and view the sql generated. The #page method from will_paginate uses its own offset and it looks like whichever is called last will gain priority.

Answer (score -1):

Which library do you use for pagination? Which Rails version do you use?

If kaminari, you can try using the method "padding"

see also this question:
[How can I set initial offset for first page in kaminari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14306096/how-can-i-set-initial-offset-for-first-page-in-kaminari)

Comment: I am using will_paginate unfortunately with rails 4.

Comment: If you use will_paginate, perhaps the answers to this question can help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513519/get-will-paginate-to-define-a-custom-offset-on-the-first-page

Comment: Thanks for the link, i'll try that solution.